# UrlHelper in Controller Action does not build correct URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue, when I'm trying to build the url for action in controller, the value of `vm` after assigning is "/". If I try to create url with other action name then everything works fine, like `Url.Action("Edit", "Contact")`.

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        string vm = Url.Action("Create", "Contact");     // equals "/"
        string editUrl = Url.Action("Edit", "Contact"); // all is fine

        return View("List", vm);
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
}
```

What's wrong with that code?

Comment: In my asp-net-mvc 5 application your code works as expected.

Comment: Please post your routing code (all of it). This is likely a case of a route matching that shouldn't be matching.

Comment: `routes.MapRoute(
 "Default",
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 new { controller = "Contact", action = "Create", id = String.Empty },
 null
);`

Comment: Strange, If i set the another action as default, code in question works fine :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because your route specifies them as defaults.

Your route is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Contact", action = "Create", id = String.Empty }, null);
```

Essentially, it is because you specify the default values `controller = "Contact", action = "Create"`. When you specify these as default you are saying if the value is not provided in the URL then use these.

For examples all these URLs are the same: `/`, `/Contact` & `/Contact/Create`. By default MVC generates you the shortest URL.

You could either change the default values or remove them like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { id = String.Empty }, null);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!